# adding approved domains into white list via rest and flow

Tags: rest, flow

i have a flow that runs and it adds domains into the white list for a given site. The flow runs fine and the domain is added into the list. Issue is, when the user for a given domain logs in with the given link it shows the message:

[image]

the flow is:

```
{
"SharingCapability":1,
"DefaultLinkPermission":0,
"DefaultSharingLinkType":0,
"SharingDomainRestrictionMode":1,
"SharingAllowedDomainList":"@{variables('Domain')}"
}
```

[image]

when you look in the admin portal you see the domain is registered to the site:

[image]

what am i missing here?

If i click on "add domain" for the site collection the domain disappears from the list and reverts back to the org list. If i was to run the get function directly it would show the domain in the list or cancel and go back into the sharing it would show back in the list:

```
https://*-admin.sharepoint.com/_api/Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant/Sites('4ba38550-0a81-47a4-8fc3-d005c25f1058')?$Select=SharingAllowedDomainList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.

must turn off the org setting make the change at the site collection level and then turn it back on at the org level:

[image]

above is to turn it off. To turn it back on you would change "sharingDomainRestrictionMode" to 1.

[image]